Coding extra command-line features in the `l3build.lua` user's script
The main context
My actual process to test via l3build always produces the following files.
$ l3build save mytest
$ l3build check mytest
Running checks on
  mytest (1/1)
          --> failed


  Check failed with difference files
  - ./build/test/mytest.luatex.diff
  - ./build/test/mytest.xetex.diff


I then do the following before checking again.
cp ./build/test/mytest.luatex.log testfiles/mytest.luatex.tlg
cp ./build/test/mytest.xetex.log testfiles/mytest.xetex.tlg

My question
In my l3build.lua script, I would like to code new l3build options. As a proof of concept, a basic printing to show that an additional option has been coded will be great. Any advice?
This will then allow adding the following features (no need to do it for me).

Automate the copy using the command l3build accept mytest.

Allow to use l3build view mytest to just open a PDF file associated to a test inside the build/test folder.



we have thought about doing 1 before although actually the same is achieved (just a bit slower)  by doing l3build save -e luatex 

https://codeberg.org/cfr/nfssext/src/branch/main/fontinst.lua adds two targets to l3build.

@cfr Can you give the names of the targets? That will help me find the useful lines of code.

fnttarg and uniquifyencs -> ntarg and utarg. second takes an optional arg. first doesn't.

Too long for a comment .... fontinst.lua defines two custom targets. The second takes an optional argument and is structured like this:
utarg = "uniquifyencs"
function uniquify(tag)
  tag = tag or "tag"
  print(tag)
  return 0
end
-- utarg
target_list[utarg] = {
  func = uniquify,
  desc = "Uniquifies encodings ONLY",
  pre = function(names)
    standalone = true
    if names and #names > 1 then
      print("Too many encoding tags specified; no more than one allowed")
      help()
      exit(1)
    else
      names = names or encodingtag or ""
    end
    return 0
  end
}

To solve partially the view problem
-- Proposed by projetmbc.

VIEW_TAG = "view"

function viewPDF(xtra_args)
  if xtra_args == nil or #xtra_args ~= 1
  then
    print("One single test file name needed!")
    return 1
  end

  local testfilename = xtra_args[1]
  
  -- cfr: use the variable in case builddir isn't this directory
  local pdffile = testfilename .. ".pdf"

  if fileexists(testdir .. "/" .. pdffile) == false
  then
    print("No PDF file found.\nSee: " .. pdffile)
    return 1
  end

-- works on Linux, but not MacOS
  local trycmd = run(testdir, "xdg-open " .. '"' .. pdffile .. '"')

  if trycmd ~= 0 then
-- Works on MacOS, but not on Linux.
    trycmd = run(testdir, "open " .. '"' .. pdffile .. '"')

    if trycmd ~= 0
    then
      print("No command to open PDF files.\nSee: " .. pdffile)
    end
  end

  return 0
end

target_list[VIEW_TAG] = {
  func = viewPDF,
  desc = "Open a PDF of tested files",
--   pre = function(xtra_args)
--   end
}


Thanks for sharing. A powerful tool that will help me.

@projetmbc thanks, but you could have posted another answer ;). I've made a few edits to make your code less dependent on os/particular locations and to keep variables local.

@projetmbc just so you know, this is the first thing I ever wrote in lua and I do not even know what object-orientated(? -based?) programming is .... caveat emptor. and I copied code from l3build which is the first thing Joseph wrote in Lua ....

we need somebody to fill in the windows version.

I have decided to publish the few tools that help me to work with l3build: https://github.com/bc-tools/for-latex/tree/l3build_xtras/l3build-xtras/src .
